# wordpress theme searchform.php with same ID when no results

Tags: html, wordpress

I provided a searchform.php in my theme. I noticed that when I search for something that does not have any results, I get the sidebar searchform and a content searchform. Both `form` elements appear with the same ID (`id="searchform"`). This would be an incorrect HTML document: `id`s must be unique.

I suspect Wordpress provides a generate_id function, but don't know where to look, or there is a tip to correct this out there.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically answered this yourself. The ID is set right in *searchform.php*. It should contain a line like so:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
```

Make the id a class instead. Done.

Comment: yes. However, I tackled it another way... answer to follow; my post count is too low to answer my own question.